# Understanding the concept of temperature vs. mean energy/heat capacity of a system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I need help understanding a concept in thermodynamics.

1. What is the relationship between temperature and mean energy?
2. What is the relationship between temperature and heat capacity?

**What I know:**

$$B=\frac{1}{kT}$$, where $B$ is the temperature parameter.

$$dB=\frac{-dT}{kT^2}$$

$$\bar E = -\frac{d(lnZ)}{dB}$$, where $\bar E$ is the average energy of the system.

I related the 2 values using the 2 equations and simplified:

$$\bar E \sim -T^2 $$

Was this on the right track? Also, can the same thing be done for heat capacity?

Comment: your derivation is wrong..see the rule for multiplication of partial derivatives..

Comment: @BruceLee I edited my question.